# svg element location in broswer

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I would like to control location of SVG in browser (viewport?)

I'm using kind of Map API. so I would like to add SVG image to the map.

However there is a problem that I cannot apply absolute position of SVG Image.

When I use Canvas, It was worked perfectly.

I think that there is a wrong when coordination is changed.

Using Canvas: It is working fine.
// create canvas element

```
function GroundOverlay(bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
        this.node = document.createElement("canvas");
        //this.node.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        //this.node.style.opacity = "0.5";
        this.node.style.position = "absolute";
        this.node.style.border = "1px solid red";
        this.node.width = 300;
        this.node.height = 200;
        this.node.style.zIndex = 3;
        this.ctx = this.node.getContext("2d");
        this.width = 300;
        this.height = 10;
        this.startX = 0;
        this.startY = 100;

        this.ctx.translate(200, 30);
        this.ctx.rotate((31.5 * Math.PI) / -180);
        this.ctx.translate(-225, -69);

        // calculate gradient line based on angle
        this.x1 = 60;
        this.y1 = 10;
        this.x2 = this.x1 + Math.cos(31.5) * 600;
        this.y2 = this.y1 + Math.sin(31.5) * 600;
        this.gradientUp = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(this.x1, this.y1, this.x2, this.y2);
        this.gradientUp.addColorStop(0, "grey");
        this.gradientUp.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)");
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.gradientUp;
        this.ctx.fillRect(this.startX, this.startY, this.width, this.height);
      }

      
      GroundOverlay.prototype = new kakao.maps.AbstractOverlay();

      
      GroundOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
        var panel = this.getPanels().overlayLayer;
        panel.appendChild(this.node);
      };

      // when event happend (zoom, center, mapType)
      // location of element is changed.
      GroundOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
        var projection = this.getProjection();
        var ne = projection.pointFromCoords(this.bounds.getNorthEast());
        var sw = projection.pointFromCoords(this.bounds.getSouthWest());

        var width = ne.x - sw.x;
        var height = sw.y - ne.y;

        this.node.style.top = ne.y + "px";
        this.node.style.left = sw.x + "px";
        this.node.style.width = width + "px";
        this.node.style.height = height + "px";
      };
```

Using SVG: when event is happeend, location is not absolute

```
  function GroundOverlay(bounds) {
          this.bounds = bounds;
          this.node = document.createElement("div");
          this.node.style.position = "absolute";
          this.svg1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
          this.svg1.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
          this.svg1.style.position = "absolute";

          // create a circle
          this.cir1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
          this.cir1.style.position = "absolute";
          this.cir1.setAttribute("cx", "80");
          this.cir1.setAttribute("cy", "80");
          this.cir1.setAttribute("r", "30");
          this.cir1.setAttribute("fill", "red");
          this.cir1.setAttribute("position", "absolute");

          // attach it to the container
          this.svg1.appendChild(this.cir1);

          // attach container to document
          this.node.appendChild(this.svg1);
        }
       
        GroundOverlay.prototype = new kakao.maps.AbstractOverlay();

        GroundOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
          var panel = this.getPanels().overlayLayer;
          panel.appendChild(this.node);
        };

        GroundOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
          var projection = this.getProjection();
          var ne = projection.pointFromCoords(this.bounds.getNorthEast());
          var sw = projection.pointFromCoords(this.bounds.getSouthWest());

          var width = ne.x - sw.x;
          var height = sw.y - ne.y;

          this.node.style.top = ne.y + "px";
          this.node.style.left = sw.x + "px";
          this.node.style.width = width + "px";
          this.node.style.height = height + "px";
        };
```

svg(circle): cannot be absolute position

https://s8.gifyu.com/images/marker1.gif

canvas(square): can be absolute position

https://s8.gifyu.com/images/marker2.gif

I tried this way (https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/)

- make a point of svgPoint
- change this point as top,left of broswer

  GroundOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  ```
         var projection = this.getProjection();
         var ne = projection.pointFromCoords(this.bounds.getNorthEast());
         var sw = projection.pointFromCoords(this.bounds.getSouthWest());

         var width = ne.x - sw.x;
         var height = sw.y - ne.y;

         this.node.style.top = ne.y + "px";
         this.node.style.left = sw.x + "px";
         this.node.style.width = width + "px";
         this.node.style.height = height + "px";


         var pt = this.svg1.createSVGPoint();
         pt.x = sw.x;
         pt.y = ne.y;
       };
  ```

Comment: Correct, SVG doesn't work that way.

Comment: Position the whole SVG directly on top of the image with the same dimensions as the image. Now you don't need absolute positioning any more because all points are relative to the image.

Answer (score 1):

> However there is a problem that I cannot apply absolute position of SVG Image.

I'm not quite sure what you mean here.  You are absolutely positioning the `<div>` that is wrapping the SVG.  Why are you also trying to set `position="absolute"` on the circle?

In any case, `position="absolute"` on a `<circle>` does nothing. That is an HTML property, not an SVG one.  However that attribute does work on an `<svg>` element, if it is the child of an HTML element (such as `<div>`).

Otherwise, the rest of your code looks more-or-less correct.  But it is hard to be 100% sure without a working example.  Please update your question with an actual (minimal) working example.

Comment: I added gif screen. I would like to make sgv circle positioning absolute like canvas square